# Why do my Mongoose models not have access to my database when they live inside an NPM module?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, npm

I'm building an API using Node, Express, and Mongo. For my data modeling, I'm using Mongoose. I'd like to move my models to a separate Node module that my API uses so that I can also reuse the models in other projects. However, I'm running into a strange problem using my Mongoose data models in my API.

When my data model source lives in an NPM module, my models cannot access my database, and any .find() or .save() calls hang and do nothing. However, if my data model source lives directly in my project, not under node_modules, then everything is fine. Here is my code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/myproject-dev'

mongoose.connect(dbURI);
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'database connection error:'));

var productModel = require('myproject-core').models.product;
console.log(productModel);
```

Here console.log() shows (I've snipped lots of stuff):

```
{ [Function: model]
  base: 
   { connections: [ [Object] ],
     plugins: [],
     models: ...
  ...
  db: 
     ...
     replica: false,
     hosts: null,
     host: null,
     port: null,
     user: null,
     pass: null,
     name: null,
     options: null,
     otherDbs: [],
     _readyState: 0,
     _closeCalled: false,
```

However, if I require() the model (with the exact same model code) in my source

```
var playerModel = require('./models/player');
console.log(playerModel);
```

I see this:

```
{ [Function: model]
  base: 
   { connections: [ [Object] ],
     plugins: [],
     models: ...
  ...
  db: 
     ...
     replica: false,
     hosts: null,
     host: 'localhost',
     port: 27017,
     user: undefined,
     pass: undefined,
     name: 'myproject-dev',
     options: { db: [Object], auth: {}, server: [Object], replset: [Object] },
     otherDbs: [],
     _readyState: 2,
     _closeCalled: false,
```

And idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was that I had mongoose listed as the [parent-require](https://www.npmjs.org/package/parent-require) NPM package helped solve the problem.